# jquery don't update element value

Tags: javascript, jquery, loading

thats my javascript:

```
<script>
 $('#DIVID01').text("Loading...");
 var Httpreq = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
 Httpreq.open("GET", 'http://httpbin.org/ip', false);
 Httpreq.send(null); 
 $('#DIVID01').text("Done");
</script>
```

The following code when i debug line by line show the first change of my DIVID01, but without debug when this function is called it takes 2 or 3 seconds to end and just the word "Done" is showed on screen. The problem is the first line code seems not work with this requisition.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to change the element, but then you are performing a **synchronous** ajax request, which is going to **lock the browser** and keep it from updating the page with your change, and then after the request is done you are changing the div value to Done.  So my assumption would be the browser is never being given a chance to redraw before you've changed it to "Done", so the "Loading..." is never seen.

Comment: If you are using JQuery, then why not use JQuery's AJAX methods, like `.get()`, `.load()` or `.post()`?

Comment: I think we need more context here, from your description your code is working as intended. Why not use `$.ajax` for your request? Should give you easier control over your request.

Comment: The 3rd parameter of `open` is the `async` option which you are setting to `false` which means the browser will block and will not refresh the view until the AJAX request finishes. You really need to think about whether disabling the asynchronous operation is wise here

Comment: ty everybody! all the coments was 
clearly explanatory

Answer (score 1):

`XMLHttpRequest` is an asynchronous request & js will not wait for the response.It will fire the asynchronous request and will immediately move to next line in this case `$('#DIVID01').text("Done");` , and will update the DOM. But in your case the expectation is the dom will be updated with 'done' after receiving the response.

Since you are already using jquery, hopefully you will not mind using [jquery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/); and

```
$.ajax({
  url:"some url",
  type:"GET",
  success:function(){
    $('#DIVID01').text("Done");
  }
})
```